# Collect Websocket streaming data in Azure Event Hub using python

Tags: python, azure, websocket, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to collect bitcoin live streaming data to Azure event hub.
Below is the code how we can do in on local machine.

How can I use this code to collect the streaming in Azure Event Hub. All examples and documents provided by Microsoft are unclear.

```
import logging
import websocket, json

cc = "btcusd"
interval = '1m'
socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{cc}t@kline_{interval}'

def on_message(ws, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    candle = json_message['k']
    is_candle_close = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']
    high = candle['h']
    low = candle['l']
    open = candle['o']
    quote = {
        'close': close,
        'high': high,
        'low': low,
        'open': open
    }
    print(f'{cc} {is_candle_close} {quote}')

def on_error(ws, error):
    logging.error(error)

def on_close(ws):
    logging.info("### closed ###")
    
logging.info("Start")
logging.info("Connecting to websocket")
websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,
                            on_message = on_message,
                            on_error = on_error,
                            on_close = on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: Do you want to know where to host that code in Azure? How to output that data into an Event Hub from your local machine? Or how to host that in Azure and output to Event Hub?

Comment: @FlorianEiden I want to host this in azure and output to Event Hub

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 tasks at hand here:

- Sending the stream of data to Event Hub. I would get started on that first, and use the [Event Hub Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send) in your local app.
- Hosting your app in Azure. Once you're done on the Event Hub side, you can deploy your app in Azure Functions. See the [Python dev guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level) for that (note that you can develop on Windows locally but will need to deploy to a Linux runtime, but that shouldn't be a problem). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python) to get started from scratch.

Functions is not the only option, but potentially here the simplest. See [that list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/developer/python/quickstarts-app-hosting) for the alternatives.

Comment: I am not able to understand how websocket stream will be sent to Event Hub using send.py from the sdk example.

Comment: From the sample, the line `await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)` is responsible for publishing your events.   Once that call completes, the Event Hubs service as acknowledged receipt of any events that you placed in the `event_data_batch`; an exception is raised for any failure.   The network details are abstracted away by the `producer`;  it is managing an AMQP connection and the needed links for ensuring transport.